Do "the masses" and "the multitude" give a sense of disdain, while "the public" doesn't?
According to dictionary definitions and notes, I found that the public is a general term referring to ordinary people in society, while the multitude and the masses might sometimes carry a sense of disdain or perhaps a disapproving tone as if they refer to people who are less educated or less important.
Is this correct? If it is, I might want to avoid using those two words in the future. In that case, could you suggest some neutral phrases to talk about "ordinary people in society"?

Your question reminds me of the title of an excellent book, Lancelot Hogben’s 1936 Mathematics for the Million.

It's a pity I haven't read it. Would you care to expand on the relevant details in the book?

Oh, I’m not saying that the book is particularly relevant, merely that the word million in its title is similar to multitudes, masses, and (the somewhat dated) common man. (It is a good book, though, if you want a taste of the beauty of math.)

Yes they do, but that sense of disdain is quite slight, unless the context says otherwise.

Collective phrases for people like “the masses”, “the crowds”, and “hoi polloi”,  and even generalized references like “the man on the street”, “John Q. Public”, and “Joe Lunchbox” can have a definite disparaging tone in English.  I can only guess that is because they plane away individual differences, and regard each (unique, complex, irreplaceable) individual as just one of interchangeable unit in a vast collective.
The only phrases I can think of that have escaped that connotation are “the public”, “the people”, and maybe “the common man” — and those have all been explicitly politicized in populist discourse (left and right) as the virtuous proletariat, although whether that is cause or effect, I don’t know.

Thank you. Do they always have that disapproving tone, or just sometimes? If I use "the masses" or "the multitude" in a positive tone, is it a problem?

IMO "the public" is still neutral in tone, cf "the public eye," "public opinion," while I agree with the "proletariat" tone of the others mentioned. @AnIELTSLearner Tone can be powerfully shaped by context. I could use terms of mild abuse as terms of endearment; I could use sarcastically positive language to convey a negative point. I could imagine uses of your suggested phrases that escape the Marie-Antoinette overtones... But it would be tricky, and hard to do without also establishing an extra ironic overtone. They are not good neutral choices for "society at large."

@AnIELTSLearner — oh, the negative connotation is slight and fragile; even if you use it deliberately to be negative, it might be missed.  If the context is positive, the words won’t sound incongruous at all. What did you expect?

The public, to me, has a connotation of civic or political involvement. If one was talking about ordinary people in the medieval era, I think it'd be odd to say "the lord raised levies from members of the public". You'd probably say "peasants/serfs" or "ordinary people". It's a good option for modern society though.
The masses and the multitude generally imply people who are less wealthy or less educated. Often, that carries a negative connotation, especially if said by somebody who is wealthy or educated.
A general rule is that these words are disparaging if the speaker doesn't include themselves in the category, and neutral-to-positive if the speaker includes themselves. "The general public doesn't understand good literature" sounds insulting even though it uses public, and "They're trying to keep riff-raff like us from voting" uses riff-raff positively, even though it's generally a disparaging term.
As an example of using these words in a positive tone, the poem written on the USA's Statue of Liberty has the phrase "Give me [America]... your huddled masses yearning to breathe free". The masses here are still poor or uneducated, but the poem uses that to say that someone without education or inherited wealth can come to the US and find opportunity.
Some other options to consider.

Sometimes, you can be more specific. For example: Eligible voters, Citizens, Residents, Texans.
Folks (informal) means regular people and has a positive association. "I hope my cooking show proves that ordinary folks can make delicious meals at home".
The people or the nation, especially with regards to political events and voting. "By electing me, the people have sent a clear message..."
Informally, placeholder names like Average Joe or Jane Doe get used metonymously to describe "a random everyday person".

